# Where is it recorded which projects unloaded from a solution in Visual Studio Professional 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, project, solution, unload

I have a solution with 6 projects loaded into Visual Studio 2019. It is a C# solution.
I unload a project, and go to the "Git Changes" tab expecting to see an unstaged change to a file somewhere that records the fact that Project A is now unloaded. There are no unstaged changes.
I reloaded the project, and still there are no unstaged changes on the "Git Changes" tab.
It must be recorded somewhere that a project of a solution is unloaded. My question is, in which file is this unloaded project status recorded?
Many thanks.

Comment: Believe it's the `.suo` file which would normally be excluded from git in most sane configurations.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever beat me to it, but regardless of the version of Visual Studio it's the solution's `.suo` file - I don't recall ever seeing a git configuration that includes that file.

Comment: @MBowen Hi, If you have solve the issue! Please consider to answer it and change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)